# How do I convert a photo from color to black and white using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Lets say we see an image of people watching tv in color and when I add the OpenGL code it turns into this:

[image: http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2008/10/18/article-1078627-02281598000005DC-210_468x382.jpg]

What is the code to convert the photo from color to black and white?

Comment: ok, lets say it. What should we do next? You should try specifying what you want to achieve, how do you think you should, have you tried any solutions, are you stuck at something? Basically, give us the info rmation to help you.

Comment: Do you really mean black & white as in monochrome, or do you mean grayscale? I'm not convinced.

Answer (score 4):

Temptative answer : use a glsl shader

```
float luminance = (in.r+in.g+in.b)/3.0;
gl_FragColor = vec4(luminance, luminance, luminance, 1.0);
```

but this is one lame question

Comment: do you mean this ? float luma = in.r*0.3 + in.g*0.59+ in.b*0.11;

Comment: Technically speaking, it would be (0.35, 0.71, 0.12) for sRGB, but given the question such details are way too technical IMHO. Where does you 0.59 comes from ? NTSC RGB ?

Comment: This works if you're indifferent regarding the color weights. Which one shouldn't be.